# I need to display 4 columns, but 2 on mobile

Tags: grid, responsive

I have an old CMS meaning I need a creative way to display:

4 columns, each cell with a linked image and a text link underneath

On mobile it would display two columns instead of four.

I'm really struggling to find an easy copy and paste solutions – I have the ability to add CSS via the CMS.

Thanks

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img class="fr-dii fr-fin" draggable="false" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change CSS like this example :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I hope you can give me your 4 column code :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use bootstrap and `col-md-3 col-sm-6` in the class of your `div`

Update:
Use the following tag to import bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How exactly do I use or add bootstrap? Do I add the CSS to the head, or is there another way to reference the css?

Comment: @Dav I've updated my answer. Please check the tags.

Comment: @Dav Please check the comment as answer if satisfied your question.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't stack in 2 columns. can you help? I updated my question with code,